# HAProxy client certificate validation

Tags: authentication, certificate, haproxy

I'm trying to setup client certificate authentication using haproxy.

With openssl I have created a CA and an intermediate CA. I want to allow only client certs signed by this intermediate CA.
What should I provide in the ca-file option : intermediate CA cert or should I provide concatenation of cert + key ?

When using cert or cert chain (cat CA + intermediate) I get the following error : ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT and the browser doesn't ask me for a cert.

here is the haproxy bind config :

```
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private ca-file /etc/haproxy/ca-chain.cert.pem verify required crt-ignore-err all
```

Thanks for your help,
Jonathan